# C# Regex optimisation

Tags: c#, regex, performance, url

I'm trying to parse URLs from a file. My regex is working for 80% of the time but I need to modify it for exceptions. It's starting to get complicated and I would like to know how could I write a nice and clean regex for this input file to get host in one group and the URI part in a second.

Ex : `http://stackoverflow.com/index.php` where `stackoverflow.com` is the host and `/index.php` is the URI.

Input file :

```
//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico
//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png
/opensearch.xml
/
#
http://www.stackoverflow.com
http://www.stackoverflow.com/
http://stackoverflow.com/
http://careers.stackoverflow.com
aaa#aaa.com
aaa.com#aaa
aaa#aaa
#aaa
#
fakedomain/index.php
fakedomain.com/index.php
fakedomain.com/
/fakedomain.com/
/index.html/
index.html
```

Regex :

```
(?:.*?//)?(.*?)(/.*|$)
```

Result :

```
1 : //cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico has 2 groups:
    cdn.sstatic.net
    /stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico

2 : //cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png has 2 groups:
    cdn.sstatic.net
    /stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png

3 : /opensearch.xml has 2 groups:
    /opensearch.xml

4 : / has 2 groups:

    /

5 : http://www.stackoverflow.com has 2 groups:
    http:
    //www.stackoverflow.com

6 : http://www.stackoverflow.com/ has 2 groups:
    www.stackoverflow.com
    /

7 : http://stackoverflow.com/ has 2 groups:
    stackoverflow.com
    /

8 : http://careers.stackoverflow.com has 2 groups:
    http:
    //careers.stackoverflow.com

7 : fakedomain/index.php has 2 groups:
    fakedomain
    /index.php

8 : fakedomain.com/index.php has 2 groups:
    fakedomain.com
    /index.php

9 : fakedomain.com/ has 2 groups:
    fakedomain.com
    /

10 : /fakedomain.com/ has 2 groups:

     /fakedomain.com/

11 : /index.html/ has 2 groups:

     /index.html/

12 : index.html has 2 groups:
     index.html

13 :  has 2 groups:
```

C# regex tester : http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

So how could I remove links with `.ico` or `.png` and adding some other fixes and also getting a nice and clean regex?

Answer (score 7):

Regular expressions are a very flexible tool, but for any sort of standardized format, there is almost always a standard parser that does the job faster and better.

Use System.Uri (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) which will handle all of the corner cases for you.

Comment: I agree with general approach of yours, however in this case `System.Uri` is buggy, and it takes some effort to hack it. Consider having `%2F` character inside URL -- you have to fix it by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I want to code it by myself. I don't care to code in ASM if it's gonna speed up the application. So if regex is not the way what is the one to take? Thx again

Comment: greenoldman: Is it buggy? Or does one need to ensure that the input is correctly unescaped via the numerous Uri class methods? Naster: if you want a correct parser that will work with any uri you come across, rather than just those that you anticipate, you'll need to use System.Uri. Or you can create your own implementation using http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986 as a reference.